# Deleting object from Angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I have a service in an Angular 2 app, `events.service.ts`:

```
const EVENTS = {
  1512205360: {
    event: 'foo'
  },
  1511208360: {
    event: 'bar'
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
  getEvents() {
    return EVENTS;
  }
  deleteEvent(timestamp) {
    delete EVENTS[timestamp];
  }
}
```

I have a `home` component which calls this service's `getEvents` method in its `ngOnInit` hook:

```
getEvents(): void {
    this.events = this.eventsService.getEvents();
    this.eventKeys = Object.keys(this.events);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEvents();
}
```

The `home` component's template simply loops over the events and prints them out, with a `delete` icon next to each one:

```
<event *ngFor="let eventKey of eventKeys" [timestamp]="eventKey" [title]="events[eventKey].event"></event>
```

This is the `event` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'event',
  templateUrl: './event.component.html',
  providers: [EventsService]
})
export class EventComponent {
  @Input() timestamp: string;
  @Input() title: string;
  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) { }

  deleteEvent(timestamp) {
    this.eventsService.deleteEvent(timestamp);
  }
}
```

Clicking the `delete` icon calls the `deleteEvent` method in the `events` service. My problem is that when I click the `delete` icon, although I can see that the event has been deleted (by `console.logging` the `EVENTS` object), the `home` component isn't updated and produces this error:

> Cannot read property 'event' of undefined

Comment: Home component isn't updated because of the error. Your explanation is not enough to detect this error.

Comment: Please show your template's code

Comment: you need to have a subject in the service , like a [shared service](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) which will notify for changes in the component

Comment: Thanks Rahul - do you have a different link? That one leads to a blank page for me.

Comment: @DanielKucal I've updated the question with more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that `HomeComponent.eventKeys` array does not linked with `HomeComponent.events` object which is linked with `EVENTS`. You set `HomeComponent.eventKeys` array one time on start of the `HomeComponent` via `Object.keys()`. All operations with `HomeComponent.events` (and `EVENTS`) do not affect `HomeComponent.eventKeys` array. So `ngFor` continues tracking the initial keys array and blows up on unexisted `events` item.

There are many possible solutions, but the main idea is to sync `HomeComponent.eventKeys` with `EVENTS`. This could be done, for example, via passing a delete-method from the `HomeComponent` to the `EventComponent` and recalculating the `eventKeys` array after deletion:

```
// HomeComponent
deleteEvent(timestamp) {
  this.eventsService.deleteEvent(timestamp);
  this.getEvents();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just created a plunk demo for this situation, enjoy: https://plnkr.co/edit/ogfmEY?p=preview

Comment: Great diagnosis. But if I don't also add `this.events = this.eventsService.getEvents()` in the `home` component's new `deleteEvent` method, I get an error: "Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

Comment: And if I do add that line, I get the same error as in my original question.

Comment: Just added `this.getEvents();` to answer. I also believe, a more elegant solution could be found from this point.

Comment: I can't make this correct because your solution doesn't work. If you remove your solution I think that the diagnosis in your first paragraph is enough to mark this correct.

Comment: @GluePear I've updated the answer and provide a runnable demo which covers the issue. It was not so easy due to Angular 4 infrastructure complexity. So the solution works as you can see.